# Installing / Compiling tarball in Windows

Tags: unit-testing, cunit

I have been asked to 'get' CUnit (the C testing framework) on my machine (windows 10 Pro x64). However, when i came to downloading it, I noticed that it was in a "tarball" file format (tar.bz2).

Ideally, I would like to be able to launch testing from CMD and possibly from eclipse, but I am having problems installing/opening the file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Please find here a link to the original CUnit file, in case it is of any use: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cunit/

Comment: Are you asking how to use file archiver to decompress archive?

Comment: You wouldn't compile a tarball. It's a compressed file. 7-Zip can open it

Comment: It sounds like you have downloaded something that needs installing.  What do the download/install instructions on sourceforge say?  Is there a Windows version (tarball is very Linux-y).

Comment: @Neil Yes, that was what it seemed like to me too, but then I discovered it was just a "file archive"-style thing. I managed to decompress it successfully using Christopher Scheiner 's advice above. Thank you anyway.